# Should functional tests in Intern (on React) generate coverage results?

Tags: reactjs, intern

I've set up Intern to test a React project created using [create-react-app](https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app) in order to perform cross-browser testing with BrowserStack. Is it expected that this would generate code-coverage results as it isn't at the moment.

To be honest I wouldn't expect it to given that the transpilation and bundling of the source files through Webpack / Babel but I just wanted to verify if this was the case.

The tests themselves are running fine (which is the main thing) but obviously it would be useful to have a code coverage report. We're using Jest / Enzyme for primary unit testing (for which we do get coverage results).

I'm really just looking for a yes/no answer here to set my expectations, but if anyone has any suggestions on getting coverage results from functional testing with this setup then that would be really useful.

Comment: are you using the `--coverage` argument when running the tests?

Comment: I'm not no... but then I don't see this documented (https://theintern.github.io/intern/) and in fact attempt to run with this option results in the message "error: unknown option `--coverage'"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get coverage results for functional tests, you'll need to load your test page(s) through Intern's test server (proxy) since the test server is what adds coverage instrumentation to the JS code. Generally, this means something like `this.remote.get('some_relative_address.html')`. If your test is loading pages from somewhere else, no coverage instrumentation will be performed.

Comment: At the moment I'm just going directly to the Webpack dev server provided as part of "create-react-app". You've described this as a "proxy" does this mean that it is sitting between the ultimate endpoint, or does it actually need to serve the pages? I've not been able to find any documentation on setting up this server - do you have a URL for more information at all?

Comment: Intern's "proxy" is just a static file server with some additional Intern-specific logic (e.g., it adds coverage instrumentation to the JS files it serves). The name "testing proxy" is just what it was originally called, and the name has stuck around. The server is always started automatically when running WebDriver tests, on port 9000 by default. For coverage to be collected, files will need to be served from this server.

Comment: OK... so *from* the server rather than *through* the server?  ... that's fine, I think that answers my question. The Intern tests will really only be for sniff testing browser compatibility so coverage isn't essential - it would have just been a bonus. I don't think the setup to serve the files from the proxy would be of benefit, and besides at the point at which they served they will have been transpiled anyway so wouldn't map back to the original source files (unless source maps are supported?). Thanks very much for providing this information - much appreciated